# Landing Page – Text Area – change text content to excerpt - roseta theme

Tags: php, function, wordpress-theming

I'm using Roseta wordpress theme. It contains a Landing page that can feature content from other pages. 
I tried to modify the roseta_lptext() function to change the content to the excerpt but it’s still not working.
This is what I changed, I changed ‘content’ to ‘excerpt’ in the apply_filters section :

```
* text area builder
*/
if ( ! function_exists( ‘roseta_lptext’ ) ):
function roseta_lptext( $what = ‘one’ ) {
$pageid = cryout_get_option( ‘theme_lptext’ . $what );
$pageid = cryout_localize_id( $pageid );
if ( intval( $pageid ) > 0 ) {
$page = get_post( $pageid );
$data = array(
‘title’ => apply_filters( ‘roseta_text_title’, get_the_title( $pageid ), $pageid ),
‘text’ => apply_filters( ‘excerpt’, get_the_excerpt( ‘excerpt’, $pageid ) ),
‘class’ => apply_filters( ‘roseta_text_class’, ”, $pageid ),
‘id’ => $what,
);
list( $data[‘image’], ) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $pageid ), ‘full’ );
roseta_lptext_output( $data );
```

Any idea on why it doesn't work ?
I'm new at this so...
Thank you !